# submenu in sidebar not expanding on click in metronic theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, themes, metronic

the orders menu should expand on click buts its not expanding. I ve imported all the necessary javascript files too. But if there is any specific js file for dropdown then let me know.I have used grails as my backend language.

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu  page-header-fixed" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200" style="padding-top: 20px">

<li class="sidebar-toggler-wrapper hide">
    <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
    <div class="sidebar-toggler">
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
</li>
<li class="nav-item start ">
    <g:link class="nav-link nav-toggle" controller="dashboard"><i class="icon-home"></i><span class="title">Dashboard</span>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    </g:link>
</li>
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_OPERATOR,ROLE_OPS_MANAGER">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
            <i class="icon-diamond"></i>
            <span class="title">Orders</span>
            <span class="arrow"></span>
        </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="nav-item  ">
            <g:link class="nav-link" action="dashboard" controller="operations">
                <span class="title">Operations Dashboard</span>
            </g:link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <g:link class="nav-link" action="search" controller="order">
                <span class="title">Order serach</span>
            </g:link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <g:link class="nav-link" action="create" controller="order">
                <span class="title">Create Order</span>
            </g:link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <g:link class="nav-link" action="import" controller="order">
                <span class="title">Import Orders</span>
            </g:link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <g:link class="nav-link" action="viewOrders" controller="operations">
                <span class="title">View Orders</span>
            </g:link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <g:link class="nav-link" action="list" controller="salesReturn">
                <span class="title">Returns</span>
            </g:link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <g:link class="nav-link" action="list" controller="shippingManifest">
                <span class="title">Manifest</span>
            </g:link>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</sec:ifAnyGranted>
</ul>
```